# SharePoint permissions to control Project Workspace

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How to control access from SharePoint permissions/security, to documents in project work-space?

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2014/02/25/document-workspace-in-sharepoint.aspx) It will create and Document workspace and permission level in SharePoint.

[Reference this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-manage-a-Document-Workspace-site-3f5beea0-1e0f-4386-888e-75aa42a4fec3)